# Unable to use Global Variables while trying to use multiple functions - JavaScript - Beginner

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, global-variables

As total JavaScript beginner I am unable to use global variable while trying to use multiple functions. The code is as follows -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        /* Global Variable example! Not working as one function called onClick. */

        function make_name_variable () { var y_name = document.getElementById('y_name').value; }
        function make_date_variable () { var y_date = document.getElementById('y_date').value; }
        function make_month_variable () { var y_month = document.getElementById('y_month').value; }
        function make_year_variable () { var y_year = document.getElementById('y_year').value; }


        function test(){
                    /*var y_name = document.getElementById('y_name').value;
                    var y_date = document.getElementById('y_date').value;
                    var y_month = document.getElementById('y_month').value;
                    var y_year = document.getElementById('y_year').value;*/

                    document.getElementById('Result').innerHTML = y_date + y_month +  y_year;


                    return true;
            }

        function compute () {

            make_name_variable ();
            make_date_variable ();
            make_month_variable ();
            make_year_variable ();
            test(); 
           }
    </script>
```

Using as:-

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="compute ()">
```

Unable to get the result as expected. I want to use the data through out the page so wanted to keep it global for all functions to use. I was not able to set it global in the conventional way as well. Declaring the variable within function gives desired result.
As you must have a realized I am a complete noob so if there are other ways to get the things done please enlighten me. Somehow I feel there must be a better and easier way to solve this.

Thanks in advance. :)

P.S: First question here. Excuse my mistakes.

Comment: A short note: If you are willing to learn Javascript, do it right and don't mess around with global variables and such nasty stuff. Look for some decent tutorials who teach you how to use JS properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var` keyword declares a variable in the current scope. If you declare a `var` inside a function, it will only exist there. [The MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) are generally very nice.

Answer (score -2):

A GOOD way to declare a global variable in Javascript would be `window.globalVariableName` rather than `var globalVariableName;` Or if you are not running your application in browser replace window with global object specific to that invironment.

The first declaration will work no matter where you are in global scope or in a function.

A BAD way to declare a global variable is

```
globalVariableName = 'Foo';
```

Because it isn't an obvious declaration and looks a lot like just forgetting the var.

And finally globalVariables is not a good thing to use. So use them thoughtfully. Try to check if they are not used already by another script say like that

```
if(window.globalVariableName === undefined) window.globalVariableName = 'Bar';
```

Try reading first chapter of 
JavaScript Patterns 
Stoyan Stefanov 
for more explanation.

UPDATE: awsering Andreas Rossberg

For example David Flanigan in Definitive Javascript Guide states in 4.6.1 what are global variables, they are properties of the global object. You can confirm this on MDN also.

About bad style, i can agree but only partially, because if you don't use the *Single var Pattern* for variable declarations like this

```
(function(){ 
    var someVar1 = '', 
        someVar2 = null, 
        someVar3 = undefined; 
})();
```

your code will look just as bad.

As to next version of EcmaScript again you are a little too brief on reference. I've read only that `this` will be handled differently in strict Javascript. If I understood you correctly this example is what you are referring to

```
function someFunction() 
{
    //'use strict';
    console.log(this); //Window or undefined
    console.log(window);// Window or Window
}
someFunction();
```

Uncommenting 'use strict'; will give undefined for this in first log, but still Window for the second log.

Comment: Actually, that is a terrible way to declare a global variable, first and foremost because it doesn't actually declare it. Use `var` in the global scope instead. Never use `window` if you don't have to.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I cannot create (if you don't like the term declare) a global variable inside a function? So if i wrap all my scripts into a self-calling function what should i do? Example: `(function(){ var globalVariable;})();` won't work apparently.

Comment: I will also like to ask you, to explain the difference between these two examples: `console.log(window.globalVariable);
window.globalVariable = 'Foo';
console.log(window.globalVariable);` and `console.log(window.globalVariable);
var globalVariable = 'Foo';
console.log(window.globalVariable);` untill you do so I believe your comment has NO PROOF

Comment: you *can* create a global name locally, the way you describe -- but it's bad style, that's all. It makes your program harder to read. FWIW, the next version of EcmaScript will discourage such style, in favour of proper lexical scoping.